# Почему добавляется три слайда вместо одного, когда я добавляю один слайд в Swiper slider?

Tags: javascript, swiper

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zn3ex8bv/

```
let swiper = new Swiper("#albums_slider", {
    direction: "horizontal",
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerView: 4,
    loop: true,
    allowTouchMove: false,
    speed: 600,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000
    },

    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    }
});
```

По какой-то загадочной причине, когда я добавляю один слайд в слайдер, добавляются три слайда. Я еще ни разу не встречал такой баг со Swiper'ом.

В начале я подумал, что баг происходит из-за того, что параметр slidesPerView задан 4, но у меня только 1 слайд в Swiper'е. Так что я попробовал увеличить количество слайдов до 4, но это не сработал, в результате в слайдере 12 слайдов.

Что делать? Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Похоже, это из-за параметра `loop: true,`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да, действительно, если убрать `loop: true`, то всё ОК. А с чем может быть связано такое поведение?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в других моих проектах я использовал параметр loop, и всё было хорошо

Comment: Думаю, немного логики здесь есть. `loop: true` стоит, значит нужна бесконечная прокрутка. Но при этом стоит `slidesPerView: 4`, то есть надо показать 4 слайда. А где их взять? Правильно, показываем один несколько раз. 1 слайд - предыдущий, 2 слайд - текущий, 3 слайд - следуюущий.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko но почему тогда, если увеличиваю количество слайдов до 4, то их становится 12. А потом если увеличу еще до 5, то их становится 13???

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko видимо это детали реализации Swiper'а. Если добавить для примера 5 разных изображений, то видно, что в слайдере их пролистывается всего 5, несмотря на то, что в HTML отображается 13

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hev1qjmk/

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko можете написать ответ, что нужно убрать `loop: true`, я помечу как решение